# How to run Oculus SDK 0.4 on OSX 10.9 with Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, oculus

In the Oculus development website, they provide a sample project with the SDK 0.4.
I tried to compile and run it. It is Successful for compiling,  without any error message.
But this project just do not run anyway. Is there any way to solve it? I did not attach the device when running, is this the problem?

Comment: Why not try attaching the device ?

Comment: Since I do not have a device on hand. And for the other demos they provide, it could run on screen.

Comment: OK - so when you say "this project just do not run anyway" - what do you mean exactly ? Any error messages ? Did you check the system logs ?

Comment: They do provide a windows version sample on Visual Studio 2012, and with that it can show on the screen and runs well. I Tried to attach my mac with the device and it does not work at all.

Comment: "does not work at all" still doesn't tell us very much - do you get any error messages when you run the code ? Does anything useful show up in the system logs ?

Comment: It shows "No issues" after I build it. And I can not press "Run" button on Xcode.

Comment: Maybe you didn't actually build an executable, just a library ? Look at the project type.

Comment: AH.  you are right. I just build the library. Seems this problem comes since I am not familiar with building projects in one solution. Thanks a lot!